# Evaluating a trigonometric limit

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ of: $$\frac{\sqrt{1+\tan x} - \sqrt{1+\sin x}}{1+x-\cos x}?$$

We cannot use L'Hôpital's rule or anything advanced like Taylor series. I reduced it to, by considering the numerator's conjugate:

$$\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x - \sin x}{1+x-\cos x}$$

But I cannot go further. Please help.

EDIT: Thinking carefully, I think I can simplify further:

$$\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x}}{\frac{1-\cos x}{x}+1}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x}$$

And perhaps the solution:

$$\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x}=\frac{1}{2}(\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x} - 1)=\frac{1}{2}(\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x \cdot x}) - 1=\frac{1}{2}(1- 1)=0$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of the question is a bit intimidating as this limit involves very basic trigonometric manipulation and standard limits like $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$. Here goes the simple solution $$\begin{aligned}L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1 + \tan x} - \sqrt{1 + \sin x}}{1 + x - \cos x}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1 + \tan x} - \sqrt{1 + \sin x}}{1 + x - \cos x}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{1 + \tan x} + \sqrt{1 + \sin x}}{\sqrt{1 + \tan x} + \sqrt{1 + \sin x}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x - \sin x}{(1 + x - \cos x)(\sqrt{1 + \tan x} + \sqrt{1 + \sin x})}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x - \sin x}{1 + x - \cos x}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\tan x\cdot \frac{1 - \cos x}{1 + x - \cos x}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\tan x\cdot \frac{2\sin^{2}(x/2)}{x + 2\sin^{2}(x/2)}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\tan x\cdot \dfrac{\dfrac{\sin^{2}(x/2)}{(x/2)^{2}}\cdot(x/2)^{2}}{x + 2\dfrac{\sin^{2}(x/2)}{(x/2)^{2}}\cdot(x/2)^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\tan x\cdot \frac{x}{4}\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{\sin^{2}(x/2)}{(x/2)^{2}}}{1 + \dfrac{x}{2}\cdot\dfrac{\sin^{2}(x/2)}{(x/2)^{2}}}\\
&= 0\cdot 0\cdot\dfrac{1}{1 + 0\cdot 1} = 0\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\sqrt{1+\tan x} - \sqrt{1+\sin x}}{1+x-\cos x}\sim_0\frac{\sqrt{1+x+\frac{x^3}3} - \sqrt{1+x-\frac{x^3}6}}{x+\frac{x^2}2}\sim_0\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^3}6\right)}{x}\sim_0\frac14 x^2$$
so the desired limit is $0$.

**Edit** Without Taylor series the calculus is tedious: let
$$f(x)=\sqrt{1+\tan x} - \sqrt{1+\sin x}$$
and
$$g(x)=1+x-\cos x$$
then
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+\tan x} - \sqrt{1+\sin x}}{1+x-\cos x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\frac{x-0}{g(x)-g(0)}=\frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}$$
and with painful calculus we find that $f'(0)=0$ and easily $g'(0)=1$ so we conclude.

Comment: You can't use taylor series as OP said.

Comment: What I have done in the edit is correct? And I like your second method :)

Comment: @Sawarnik Yes correct!

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome:) @Sawarnik

Comment: The taylor approach is not very rigorous...

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+\tan x}-\sqrt{1+\sin x}}{1+x-\cos x}$$
Here the form is $(\frac{0}{0})$, so we can apply L'hospital rule.
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+\tan x}}\sec^{2}x-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+\sin x}}\cos x}{1+\sin x}=0.$$

Comment: What about "cannot use LH" part? :)

Comment: Taylor Series and Lhopital's rule can't be used.